# Receive an urlenconded in Spring Boot API

Tags: java, spring-boot, webhooks

I need to receive a request from a webhook from a third party API.

Post content is an urlenconded in following format:

> event=invoice.created&data%5Bid%5D=value1&data%5Bstatus%5D=pending&data%5Baccount_id%5D=value2

The problem is serialize this params data[id] with these square brackets. I'm getting an error in spring boot:

> Invalid property 'data[account_id]' of bean class [br.com.bettha.domain.dto.IuguWebhookDto]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'data[account_id]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [IuguDataDto(id=null, account_id=null, status=null, subscription_id=null)]

My controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/subscription-invoice", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
@ApiOperation(
        value="Create a subscription invoice from Iugu's webhook",
        response= Invoice.class,
        notes="This Operation creates a subscription invoice from Iugu's webhook")
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
public ResponseEntity<Invoice> createSubscriptionInvoice(IuguWebhookDto iuguWebhookDto) {
    try {
        Invoice invoice = paymentService.createSubscriptionInvoiceFromIugusWebhook(iuguWebhookDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(invoice, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

IuguWebhookDto.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class IuguWebhookDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5557936429069206933L;

    private String event;
    
    private IuguDataDto data;
```

IuguDataDto.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class IuguDataDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5557936429069206933L;

    private String id;

    private String account_id;

    private String status;

    private String subscription_id;
```

How can I receive these request params as an object in Spring Boot?

Comment: Pretty sure it should be data.id, data.account_id, data.status, ... instead of data[id], data[account_id], data[status], ...

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope, but unfortunately, it's not. Second API documentation, post content is data[id], etc. https://dev.iugu.com/docs/referencias-gatilhos.

I do not have access to change API implementation. It's a third party API, then I need to know if there is a way to get this values in Spring Boot in this format.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Iugu Webhooks API. To solve, i just stringify the raw data sent by Iugu, remove the unwanted characters, and then parse again the object to get the variables that i want.

```
    var dataReceived = JSON.stringify(req.body).replace('data[id]','id').replace('data[status]','status').replace('data[account_id]','account_id');

  var finalData = JSON.parse(dataReceived);

  return res.status(200).send(finalData.id);
```